# Is it safe to delete .pkg/.dmg files after installation?

Tags: macos, install

Can I delete a `pkg` `dmg` `zip` file after I install its content? I mean if this is a little app can I delete the installation file without breaking the installed application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question(s), generally speaking, yes, you can delete the container file whether it be a .pkg, .dmg or .zip file. This of course assumes that all content of the container file has been installed. In other words, some .dmg files might contain extras in a separate folder within that are not installed when you drag and drop the app into Applications.

So use common sense when making the decision to delete the container. Obviously if the container contains a single file and you install it, then there is no need to retain it if you don't mind downloading again if for some reason it's needed again.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes. You can delete the .pkg/.dmg/.zip file after installing the app. It will not affect the app as both files are different. These packages are just containers.

Answer (score 4):

Take care that some installers (.pkg files) may also contain a menu/button for properly uninstalling the app. Browse the app's doc to see if this is mentioned. If so, it is a good idea to keep the .pkg file somewhere (external drive, ..)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's no longer required to run the application so it's safe to delete. Personally I like to archive a copy first, in case I ever want to re-install an app or version of an app that's no longer available. So at this point I have a network drive with thousands of DMG and PKG files on it...